# raspberry pi4 and PiHole with connection problems

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, pi

I use a Raspberry Pi with PiHole and 4 or 5 weeks ago something happened. The PiHole stopped working and I had to restart my Pi to get everything back running. But my problem is not about PiHole it is about the raspberry. When these problems occure I can't connect via ssh. So I have to restart it again because I usually connect via ssh. After a restart it takes two or three days and the pi stopps working again. When I check the pi it seems running, status led is blinking and the fan is spinning.

Because I couldn't explain the problem I installed everything from scratch. But after 2 days the problem occured again and I don't know where to start. The pi was running for a year without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem happens when there's a general power outage or blackout (or router reboot) who knows, and the Pi loses ethernet connection (if this is the case) with your router. I can tell because same symptoms started happening to me on a Pi4 (not so Pi Zero W with a pihole test bench as well). My understanding is that if you're using DHCP in /etc/dhcpcd.conf, once you lose connection, it is unable to request for it again (experts will let us know), on the other hand if you use a static IP, the network event handler could request for its assigned IP again, either way I created a script that restarts the network in case it doesn't finds connection between your Pi & the Gateway (router), all improvement suggestions are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Test 5 seconds Ping against Gateway every 60 seconds, if fail, restart network interface

INTERFACE=$(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $8}')  # Node's Interface
GATEWAY=$(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')    # Node's gateway

WAIT_SEC=60                     # 1 minute
PING_WAIT=5                     # 5 sec

while :; do

    # Wait a bit upon reboot
    sleep $WAIT_SEC

    # Command
    ping -w $PING_WAIT $GATEWAY 2>&1 >> /dev/null

    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then

        sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE down
        sleep 5
        sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE up

    fi

done
```

My setup is, I created a cronjob with the following sintax helped by screen command:

```
@reboot screen -d -m sudo bash /home/pi/connection_script/check_connection.sh
```

So next time Pi reboots, the script is run and you can see what's the "screen command" PID with **screen -list** then attach to with with screen -r 123 where 123 is the screen Pid.

If you customize your script, and want to debug it add (-xv) to shebang like this

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

And when you runit, run like:

```
bash -x check_connection.sh
```

Same from cronjob + screen so you can see what the script is doing.